# Compute eigenvalues with Arpack

Tags: eigenvalues, arpack

I am using Arpack to compute the eigenvalues of the problem $\lambda Mx = Ax$ with reverse shift method with complex shift. $A$ and $M$ are real, $M$ is symmetric. Then, I use znaupd e zneupd. I use superLU to solve the system. Everything seems to be ok. I wrote a function that takes the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors computed with Arpack and put them in the original problem: $\lambda Mx -Ax = \text{residual}$. The norm of the residual is supposed to be almost zero or very small. Anyway, I obtain an error of $10^{-3}$ that is quite high! Do you have any idea where the problem can come from? I hope it is quite clear.

Thanks,

Nora

Comment: What are the matrices' condition numbers? How big are the matrices, and how large are their coefficients?

Comment: Hi, the dimensions are very big: 571538 X 571538. The error is bigger as soon a parameter, the rigidity, is increased. In fact, the matrices comes from a finite element code that solves a fluid-structure problem. Increasing the rigidity, makes a block of A greater.

Comment: Can you calculate the condition numbers of $A$, $M$, and the eigenvector matrix? Those are very important for the size of residuals. How big are the elements of those matrices?

Comment: As condition number you mean $\frac{|\lambda_{max}|}{|\lambda{min}|}$? I can try to compute with matlab but I do not know if the matrices are too big. With Arpack I computed only the first 25 eigenpairs. You suggest that if the matrices are ill conditioned it can be a problem?

Comment: That's only for normal matrices. Try matlab's `cond` and `condest`. Of course: relative error of $\lambda$ should behave something like $O(\kappa(V)\epsilon_\text{mach})$; condition of $A$, $M$ will also affect the computation. Also, try computing relative error instead of absolute error; that can be misleading when coefficients of $A$, $M$, $x$ are very large.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. The eigenvalues with arpack are well computed. The problem is that those eigenpairs, when are put in the original problem: $\lambda Mx−Ax=residual$ , do not give a residual that is very small.

Comment: Depending on the properties of the matrices involved, you might not be justified in expecting a small residual. Also, "well computed" still involves some amount of numerical error, and what you are saying is not nearly enough to tell *how much*.

Comment: For "well computed" I mean that the exit criteria of Arpack is satisfied and when I exit znaupd function info =0 that correspond to normal exit.

Comment: Since you have access to MATLAB, why don't you try to solve this eigenvalue problem with the eigs() function? eigs also uses ARPACK but you can compare its results with yours. If you have MATLAB on the same system where you are running SuperLU/ARPACK, MATLAB will likely be able to accommodate these large matrices.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My code is written in C++. I must find a way to save those matrices and then to load them in matlab. Anyway, @Kirill I think that the cond number, at least for M, is very high since this matrix is singular.

Comment: If your matrices are in compressed sparse column format for SuperLU, it is straightforward to use the MATLAB c-api to create a sparse mxArray and then write that to a .mat file that MATLAB can read. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/custom-applications-to-read-and-write-mat-files.html

Comment: There is no reason for the residual to be small. If, for example, your eigenvalues are of size $10^6$ and the elements of your matrix are of size $10^{12}$, then a residual of size $10^{-3}$ is exceptionally small. What matters is that the residual is *small compared to the other quantities in your equation*. For example, I would compute $\frac{\|Ax-\lambda Mx\|}{Ax}$. This should give you a more accurate measure of whether the residual is large or small.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you. You mean: $\frac{\|Ax-\lambda Mx\|}{\|Ax\|}$, right? Anyway I saved my matrices and computed the eigenvalues with Matlab and I obtain the following warning: Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 2.978632e-19. > In eigs>AminusSigmaBsolve at 1210 In eigs>@(v)AminusSigmaBsolve(Bmtimes(v)) at 149 In eigs at 264. Maybe it is a problem of condition number...

Comment: MATLAB says that A-sigma\*M is "close to singular." As an engineer, I would say it *is* singular.;-) What value did you input for sigma? I suggest trying to define sigma to be close to what you think the lowest eigenvalue might be.